# Between operator using column(+)

Tags: plsql

We have a code using column(+) inside between condition. Kindly help in understanding the same :
`AND b.dat_periodo_rifer BETWEEN a.dat_ini_val(+) AND NVL(a.dat_fin_val(+)- 1,b.dat_periodo_rifer)`

Need to understand what is the use of column(+) notation.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates that the preceding column is the outer join column in a join. Note that Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alot